# Expected binary or unicode string, got 0.0

Tags: unicode, tensorflow, binary

I'm training my first model with TensorFlow, but I keep having this error:

> Expected binary or unicode string, got 0.0

I followed TensorFlow linear model tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide) and applied it on my own dataset.

This is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 289, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 455, in fit
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 953, in _train_model
    features, labels = input_fn()
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in train_input_fn
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in input_fn
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <dictcomp>
  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 473, in make_tensor_proto
    append_fn(tensor_proto, proto_values)
  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 109, in SlowAppendObjectArrayToTensorProto
    tensor_proto.string_val.extend([compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values])
  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 109, in <listcomp>
    tensor_proto.string_val.extend([compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values])
  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 65, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got 0.0
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using? It's working for me in Python 3.4 and TensorFlow at ~head.

Comment: Hei, I just found out that I made a mistake in here (after lambda):
df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df_train["income_bracket"].apply(lambda x: ">50K" in x)).astype(int)
df_test[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df_test["income_bracket"].apply(lambda x: ">50K" in x)).astype(int)

Thanks anyway

Comment: What did you do to fix this?